# Pass function with dynamic value to child widget

Tags: flutter, parameters

I need have this function in a parent widget

```
User? _user;

void _onChangeUser(User? user) {
  setState(() {
    _user = user;
  });
}
```

I want to pass it to a child widget that receives a function with a dynamic argument, so on the parent widget build method I do:

```
return _ChildView(
   onPress:  _onChangeUser,
);
```

And on my child widget I want to pass this function, but let it have a dynamic argument, like this:

```
class _ChildView extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ChildView({
    Key? key,
    required this.onPress,
}) : super(key: key);

final ValueChanged<dynamic> onPress;
```

However, flutter is not allowing this. The argument type 'void Function(User?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(dynamic)'. I would expect to be able to assign a User? to a dynamic value.

How do I go about this?

I have also tried

```
final Function(dynamic) onPress;
```

but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function inside `_ChildView` has a type `dynamic` as parameter, instead your function `_onChangeUser` has a type of `User?` as a parameter.

If you want the `onPress` function inside `_ChildView` to accept arguments of different types each time it is called, you can define it to accept a generic type `T` as follows:

```
    class _ParentViewState extends State<ParentView> {
      User? _user;

      void _onChangeUser(User? user) {
        setState(() {
          _user = user;
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return _ChildView(onPress: _onChangeUser);
      }
    }

    class _ChildView<T> extends StatelessWidget {
      final Function(T) onPress;
      const _ChildView({Key? key, required this.onPress}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
      }
    }
```

Comment: No, I don't want that, because the child can receive a different function with and argument of a different type. I want the argument of the child function to be able to be of any type (that is what dynamic is supposed to be, for me) and User? *is* any type

Comment: @user3808307 i have updated my answer in order tu fulfill your request

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
final Function(dynamic) onPress
```

to a general Function type

```
final Function onPress
```

and call it with

```
onPress.call();
```